# Was this character dead or alive in The Haunting of Bly Manor?

Tags: the-haunting-of-bly-manor

In the Netflix series ***The Haunting of Bly Manor***, we find that the lady in the lake is Viola. However, I can't understand if Viola was alive or dead, as whenever she came out of the lake, everyone could see her which is quite opposite to the general 'be visible to only a few special people and at certain times' pattern of ghosts.

Comment: The second tag refers to the name of the anthology series that this belongs to. I've added usage guidance to it to clarify that they are related. The Haunting of Hill House is season one of The Haunting anthology series and The Haunting of Bly Manor is season 2.

Comment: she has to be dead, given her longevity and ability to survive without oxygen; in the end her face slowly erodes away like many other ghosts.

Comment: Here is an in-depth 1.5 hour long summary of the show, combined with analysis and an interview with the creator: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=waqLeaJ9tl4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Forgive me but it seems like you missed the entire plot of the show. It's well established that she is dead and a ghost.

- She lived in the 1600s
- We see her murdered
- We see her grave stone
- Her husband remarries her sister
- She haunts the manor every decade or so

Comment: I had the impression that she walked around quite regular and we only get to see some significate events throughout that the time. Iirc (and to be honest i binge watched all but one episode yesterday) the narrator only told that she hadn't noticed that decades had passed which for me is no 100% argument that this is the period she wakes up